# Is there any way to create a dashboard shows both brekdowns and running in Powerbi?

Tags: report, powerbi, dashboard

[Data Sample[][1]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81FU2.png)I want to create a dashboard for a machine production line. These machines are running for 24 hours but sometimes breakdowns occur. I need a bar chart that shows both down- and up-times. I've tried it with Powerbi, but I'm new to it and it failed.

How can I to create a chart such as this:

[image: Example Bar Chart for Breakdowns and Runnings]

[Sample Data for only 3 columns (because I'll use only these three columns)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz15e.png)

Comment: Could you provide sample data so that we can give you idea. Also the example you showed does not show clearly what exactly is your desired design needed.

Comment: Please provide some raw data of your machine line so we can help you better. Your image is very small, a bit bigger would help to understand what the end result should be.

Comment: I've added sample data. Thanks for your help

Comment: Sample data means a table(s) with columns and some rows of data in it so we understand your data structure, please provide this..

Comment: I've added my data preview. I only need these three columns. Thanks

Comment: do you need something like this https://imgur.com/a/jK7LgZ0

Comment: I cannot open the image

Comment: I could see the image. Thanks but not like this. It must be on the one bar chart as horizontal